# When should I make a closure mut?

Tags: rust, closures, mutable, mutability

Let's say I have this code:

```
let mut s = "hi".to_string();
let c = || s.push_str(" yo");
c();
```

It doesn't compile and generates this error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `c` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable                 
   --> src\test.rs:120:9
    |
119 |         let c = || s.push_str(" yo");
    |             -      - calling `c` requires mutable binding due to mutable borrow of `s`  
    |             |
    |             help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut c`
120 |         c();
    |         ^ cannot borrow as mutable

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
error: could not compile `test` due to previous error
```

Why `c();` cannot borrow as mutable? It cannot borrow what as mutable? `c`? In order to make it work, I have to change it to:

```
let mut s = "hi".to_string();
let mut c = || s.push_str(" yo");
c();
```

But here I'm just defining a closure `c`. I'll not modify it, like `c = || x;`. Why must define it as `let mut c`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But here I'm just defining a closure `c`. I'll not modify it, like `c = || x;`. Why must define it as let `mut c`?

Because a closure is fundamentally a structure, each captured item being a member of that structure.

So your code is roughly equivalent to this:

```rust
struct S<'a>(&'a mut String);
impl S<'_> {
    fn call(&mut self) {
        self.0.push_str("yo");
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut s = "hi".to_string();
    let c = S(&mut s);
    c.call();
}
```

And that fails to compile with more or less the same error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `c` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
13 |     let c = S(&mut s);
   |         - help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut c`
14 |     c.call();
   |     ^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Now you might object that that's because I defined `fn call(&mut self)`, but if you don't you get the internal part of the same error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*self.0` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
7 |     fn call(&self) {
  |             ----- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut self`
8 |         self.0.push_str("yo");
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

That is you can't modify an `&mut` through an `&`. Because if you did you could create multiple `&`s to the same `&mut` through which you could modify the pointee, and that would essentially give you multiple `&mut`.

Which is not allowed by Rust's semantics:

> At any given time, you can have *either* one mutable reference or any number of immutable references.

Answer (score 2):

It may not look like `c` needs to be mutable because you aren't modifying `c` itself, but for closure types, the `mut` keyword is what allows it to mutate any external state. It changes the type of the closure to be a [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), which the docs refer to as "a mutably capturing closure".

Answer (score 2):

It's about ownership. `mut` here does not mean that you will mutate `c`, but that you require `mut`-level access to the closure in order to execute it.

`c` borrows `s` mutably. This should be fairly obvious, because calling `c()` modifies `s`.

Now imagine if `c` would be usable without `mut`:

```rust
let mut s = "hi".to_string();
let c = || s.push_str(" yo");

let c1 = &c;
let c2 = &c;

c1();
c2();
```

Here, both `c1` and `c2` would have mutable access to `s` simultaneously, which is not possible according to Rusts borrowing rules. This is prevented automatically by the compiler, as it changes the type of the closure to `FnMut` as soon as you access a variable mutably from within the closure.

Then, you need `mut` access to the closure to execute it and the case becomes a compiler error:

```
let mut s = "hi".to_string();
let mut c = || s.push_str(" yo");

let c1 = &mut c;
let c2 = &mut c;

c1();
c2();
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `c` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
4 | let c1 = &mut c;
  |          ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
5 | let c2 = &mut c;
  |          ^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
6 | 
7 | c1();
  | -- first borrow later used here
```